# s it possible to use =substitute on x in a linear equation and solve it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

everyone. I'm trying to do an iterative equation solver, where I put an equation then each iteration substitutes the X for a value then solves it. I'm having a hard time since the iterated function is considered a string. Any help is appreciated, thank you. The equation needs to be dynamic and be solved via iterations.

I tried calling the =substitute cell and end up having invalid data, since it reads as string.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: And make up your mind about the tags. Excel is not Google sheets

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13FRmjwSs3VBe6rqacFvgEZcKDbTuUjqA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100544135637515775912&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: do you see it now?

Comment: Yup, so basically for C9 to C24 to be the outcome of B9 to B24. I really don't know how to implement it. I tried calling the equation itself which is B2:C2

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=BYROW(A9:A24, LAMBDA(ii, INDEX(QUERY(, 
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(B2, "\^\d+", REPT("*x", 
 REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "\^(\d+)")-1)), "\(", "*("), "x", ii&"")), 2)))
```

[image]

### logic:

- caret `^` is not supported by QUERY so we first transform `^2` into an alternative. we know `x^2` is equal to `x*x` so we extract that `2` and subtract 1 and REPT `*x` one time
- next, we need to add multiplication as `()()` needs to become `()*()` same as `50x` to `50*x`
- then we substitute `x` with value and evaluate the string with QUERY's SQL ## logic:

basically, we transform your:

```
-50(x)-1/2(-9.81)(x^2)+35
```

into:

```
-50*(0)-1/2*(-9.81)*(0*0)+35
-50*(1)-1/2*(-9.81)*(1*1)+35
-50*(2)-1/2*(-9.81)*(2*2)+35
etc.
```

---

## UPDATE:

`x^n` where `n` is `<1` are unachievable with REPT method and QUERY does not support roots so we can use a script to convert a text string into the formula

poor script example:

```
function onEdit(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var source1= sheet.getRange('F7');
  var source2= sheet.getRange('F8');
  var formula1 = source1.getValue();
  var formula2 = source2.getValue();
  var target1 = sheet.getRange('B7');
  var target2 = sheet.getRange('B8');
  target1.setFormula(formula1);
  target2.setFormula(formula2);
}
```

where F7 contains:

```
=BYROW(A7:A23, LAMBDA(i, "POW("&INDEX(QUERY(, "select "&REGEXREPLACE(
 SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(B3, "(.+)\^"), ")(", ")*("), "x", i&"")), 2)&","&
 REGEXEXTRACT(B3, "\^\((.+)\)")&")"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just did the same lines for three other methods, and I'm getting error now? I don't understand. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-6LFxE6x3gcWftTiVltpvzag77S95MygJVZPjTSUlM/edit?usp=sharing